# What is the purpose of ArrayAdapter in building navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm new in android dev, and I was working on navigation drawer based on tutorial here: [Android Custom Navigation Drawer](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/)

In that tutorial, he created a CustomDrawerAdapter class extends from ArrayAdapter

My question is:
What is an ArrayAdapter?

What is ArrayAdapter/CustomDrawerAdapter used for here? (for a navigation drawer)

More specifically, what does the getView method of ArrayAdapter/CustomDrawerAdapter do?

ps. I've read the android reference, but it doesnt help much.
Especially, the getView method doesnt even have an discription.

code for CustomDrawerAdapter

```
package com.example.tabapp;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItem> {

      Context context;
      List<DrawerItem> drawerItemList;
      int layoutResID;

      public CustomDrawerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,
                  List<DrawerItem> listItems) {
            super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
            this.context = context;
            this.drawerItemList = listItems;
            this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;

      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            DrawerItemHolder drawerHolder;
            View view = convertView;

            if (view == null) {
                  LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                  drawerHolder = new DrawerItemHolder();

                  view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
                  drawerHolder.ItemName = (TextView) view
                              .findViewById(R.id.drawer_itemName);
                  drawerHolder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);

                  view.setTag(drawerHolder);

            } else {
                  drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) view.getTag();

            }

            DrawerItem dItem = (DrawerItem) this.drawerItemList.get(position);

            drawerHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(dItem.getImgResID()));
            drawerHolder.ItemName.setText(dItem.getItemName());

            return view;
      }

      private static class DrawerItemHolder {
            TextView ItemName;
            ImageView icon;
      }
}
```

Comment: There's a [talk from Google I/O 2010](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) on the topic. They discuss the ListView which has a different role than NavigationDrawer, but the underlying adapter solution is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a `ListView listView`,  an adapter is then used to set the data source for this `listView` : `listView.setAdapter(customAdapter)`

This `listView` can have multiple list items which is then provided by the adapter. Generally, when initializing an adapter, you pass some data source to the adapter. The adapter then uses the data from this data source to generate views for the listView and this generation of views is done inside the `getView()` method.

So, if the adapter wants to know how the first list item should look like, it'll call getView() with position 0. Now your getView() method should handle how the 0th view looks like.

What we generally do is to store the relevant data in an Arraylist, then fetch the 0th object from that arraylist to generate the view.

In the drawer's case, see this line :
`DrawerItem dItem = (DrawerItem) this.drawerItemList.get(position);`

Here is fetches the relevant object from the `drawerItemList` for the position and then sets it to the views :

```
drawerHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(dItem.getImgResID()));
drawerHolder.ItemName.setText(dItem.getItemName());
```

These views are inflated with the layout that you want your particular view to have :

```
view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
```

At the end you return this view with the relevant data which is then displayed in the list.

There are a lot of the other things the adapter does but in the nutshell this is how it works.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't find such explanation anywhere and don't understand why this question voted down